# Can't run Protractor tests with Chrome headless and Xvfb

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, headless, xvfb

I've been searching and trying different solutions for almost a week, but still not find the answer.

First off, my environment:
Server Debian 8 (no-GUI), Protractor 4.0.9, Selenium Server 2.53.1 (started using webdriver-manager), Chromedriver 2.24.417424, Chrome 54.0.2840.100, Firefox 43.0, Xvfb

I'm trying to use headless Chrome to execute my tests but Chrome is never able to start.
Notice that I'm able to run my tests using Firefox headless perfectly fine.
This my output when trying to run a test using Chrome:

```
    [18:38:31] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.13 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'testing', ip: '10.128.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.7.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
[18:38:31] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.13 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'testing', ip: '10.128.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java.version: '1.7.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at WebDriverError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:639:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:538:13)
    at client_.send.then.response (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:472:11)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
    at asyncRun (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:329:24)
    at Builder.build (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)
    at Hosted.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:37:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:198:43)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:277:30
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[18:38:31] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

It is always the same.
I'm able to run both Chrome and Firefox using Xvfb normally, and chromedriver runs fine when started manually.

This is the command I use to start Xvfb:

```
Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

Output when starting chromedriver manually:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your protractor process using the command `xvbf-run protractor configuration.js`